# main() functions return value?

Tags: c

Anyone please tell me where the main() function of the 'C' language returns its value?

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456335/return-value-of-main-in-windows

Comment: It returns a value to whoever started it up. If you started it from a shell, it returns the value to the shell. If you started it from an IDE (i.e. Visual Studio), then the return code is sent to Visual Studio. If you double clicked an executable on the desktop... well, it gets returned to whichever Windows process spawned him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C's `main` function returns an int... that int goes to the program which executed it (the parent process, if you will) as an exit status code.

Specifically, on most operating systems, a 0 exit code signifies a normal run (no real errors), and non-zero means there was a problem and the program had to exit abnormally.

Comment: It might not go to the OS, it might go to the shell.

Comment: More generally, it goes to the process that invoked the executable.

Comment: Mmm, that's true. Let's fix that.

Comment: @Jason How does it get from one process to the shell without going through the OS?

Comment: @Platinum It doesn't go to the parent process. The OS collects the return code when the process dies. There a parent process might have closed but the return value can still be read by other interested processes.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Edit it yourself then, I'm tired of arguing semantics. I have to imagine it'd be largely platform-dependent exactly HOW the exit code gets to the parent process anyway.

Comment: Tangentially relevant, stdlib.h defines EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE for platform-independently indicating the successful or botched run of the program.

Answer (score 4):

The return value if the main() function is used as the exit status code of the program.

In a shell you can get the exit status of a program using $?, example:

```
./prog
exit_status=$?
```

Answer (score 2):

From the C99 Standard:

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;

and then

> **7.20.4.3 The `exit` function**
>
> 5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination* is returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

In short, the return value of `main` is returned to the host environment in an implementation-defined form.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function is at libery to return its value at any point at which it pleases. You simply write:

```
return my_return_value;
```

and it's game over.

Comment: @Jason Like I said, *at any point at which it pleases*. Once its done, it returns its return value.

Comment: @Jason Are interpreting that the question is regarding how a process can read the return value of another process?

Answer (score 0):

A general statement is: **Function returns a value to the host environment.**

So main() will return value to any program or shell which is hosting that piece of code or to the OS.

return value 0 is considered as successful execution