# Why in C99 Xcode, an 'int' require a return on the end, but in Codeblocks not?

Tags: c, c99

I got a code from my teacher in Codeblocks C99, but I'm using Xcode and I tried to run it but Xcode  want me to put a return to the end of an int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "string.h"

void usage(char *prg) {
    printf("String pointer demo, usage: %c <text>\n", prg);
}

int process(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int l = strlen1(argv[1]);
    {
        char *target = malloc(l);
        if (!target)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        printf("Copy of %s is %s\n", argv[1], strcpy1(target, argv[1]));
    }
    strlen1(NULL);
    strcpy1(NULL, NULL);
    return 0;               // it's failing here but codeblocks it worked
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("String pointer demo\n");
    if (argc == 1) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return process(argc, argv);
}
```

why is this?

Comment: If a function is declared to return a value, it *must* return a value. Otherwise you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ...only if the returned value is used in the caller..is not it?

Comment: And speaking of *undefined behavior*, don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is important and means that a string for X characters need space for X+1 to fit the terminator. And the `strlen` function returns the length of a strings *not* counting the terminator.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - In this case, return value of `process` is used as the return value of `main`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Good question, and I'm sure it's been written here on SO before. :) (And no, I don't know the answer or where to find such a question.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sir, I think most of the function calls are custom functions, not the standard ones.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Sure...but does that count as _usage_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You're probably right about the functions, but it still seems very suspect. Even more the calls passing `NULL` as arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that is why..maybe it needs more clarification from OP before we put our efforts into it. :)

Comment: @Joseph you have to elaborate on your problem. Do you mean you have a build error? Then what error? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and then edit your question to tell us what possible error or warning or compiler message in general that you get.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I guess it goes to the operating system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456335/return-value-of-main-in-windows

Comment: @RishikeshRaje or the shell

Comment: @RishikeshRaje in general..whichever process invoked the `main()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - So, I guess that the return value would be used from the perspective of the C compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “If a function is declared to return a value, it must return a value.”: This is not correct; the C standard does not require that a function declared to return a return a value. The behavior is undefined only if an attempt is made to use a value when one is not returned.

Comment: Codeblocks and Xcode are not compilers but IDEs. The error/warning/whatever you get comes from the compiler the IDE uses to translate your code.

Comment: Is there any point in returning `EXIT_FAILURE` on failure and not returning a value of success, when this means you technically can't check for the failure status as you don't know if any value was returned? =)

Comment: BTW unless your teacher gave this code as an assignment to find and fix all the bugs, get another teacher.